# Load vue-cli-version-marker from local

Tags: vue.js

When executing `vue ui`, without an admin cmd, I have the following error:

```
Failed to get response from https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-version-marker
```

When executing with the admin cmd, it works. It is certainly due to the company's policies.

Is it possible to load vue-cli-version-marker from a local location and not from online to bypass this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled my anti-virus and vpn.
It worked for me.

Thanks